# Change the text of several elements on a timer with onClick

Tags: javascript, element, swap

I have a button that `onClick` starts a timer that calls a function and passes the counter.  I used an alert box to see that I was getting counter as 0.

If counter is 0, it should load the table with the text (it skips it) it goes to the second if statement and only load the first element Rep is 2?

My code:

```
 function startTimer(){
    counter =0;
        document.getElementById("RGlights").innerHTML = '<img src="../../images/Screen-Images/G-on-lighs.jpg" class="lightsRG" />';

     setInterval(function(){Hi(counter)},3000);

     function Hi(counter)
     {
                //alert('Hello ' + counter);

        while (counter < 3)
        {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
        document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "Rep: 1";
        document.getElementById("peak").innerHTML = "Peak: 549.3";
        document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "Avg: 575.25";
        //counter +=1;      
        }

        if (counter == 1)
        {       
        document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "Rep: 2";
        document.getElementById("peak").innerHTML = "Peak: 549.3";
        document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "Avg: 575.25";
        document.getElementById("RGlights").innerHTML = '<img src="../../images/Screen-Images/R-on-lighs.jpg" class="lightsRG" />';
        //counter +=1;

        } 
        else
       {
        document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "Rep: 3";
        document.getElementById("peak").innerHTML = "Peak: ";
        document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "Avg: ";
        document.getElementById("RGlights").innerHTML = '<img src="../../images/Screen-Images/R-G-off-lighs.jpg" class="lightsRG" />';
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML =  '<img  src="../../images/Screen-Images/stop.jpg" width="165" height="63" border="0" /> ';
        }
            };
      counter +=1``
       }; /*   */
```

Comment: This is really simple and basic debugging, that you could even do using paper and pen: On `counter == 0` you set `counter += 1`, so counter becomes 1 which will match the next `if (counter == 1)` immediately

Comment: Also keep your else part code inside the {}. In ur case apart from the 1st statement(rep) all other statements will be executed always even the counter value is 0 or 1

Comment: I edited it, but now I don't get inside at all...? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs some work:

```
    function startTimer() {
        //counter is a global variable so Hi will have access to it, don't need to send it as a parameter
        var counter = 0; 
        document.getElementById("RGlights").innerHTML = '<img src="../../images/Screen-Images/G-on-lighs.jpg" class="lightsRG" />';
        //use setTimeout, setInterval will be calling Hi infinitely 
        setTimeout(Hi, 3000);

        function Hi() {                
            if (counter < 3) {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "Rep: 1";
                    document.getElementById("peak").innerHTML = "Peak: 549.3";
                    document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "Avg: 575.25";
                    //counter +=1;
                }
                // use else if here, otherwise the else will be executed the first time when counter == 0
                else if (counter == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "Rep: 2";
                    document.getElementById("peak").innerHTML = "Peak: 549.3";
                    document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "Avg: 575.25";
                    document.getElementById("RGlights").innerHTML = '<img src="../../images/Screen-Images/R-on-lighs.jpg" class="lightsRG" />';
                    //counter +=1;

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML = "Rep: 3";
                    document.getElementById("peak").innerHTML = "Peak: ";
                    document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "Avg: ";
                    document.getElementById("RGlights").innerHTML = '<img src="../../images/Screen-Images/R-G-off-lighs.jpg" class="lightsRG" />';
                    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = '<img  src="../../images/Screen-Images/stop.jpg" width="165" height="63" border="0" /> ';
                }
                counter += 1;
                //you need to recall setTimeout
                setTimeout(Hi, 3000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add the details Carorus, I understand now, got it working and have been cleaning it up. Much appreciate !

Comment: Good to know, it'll be helpful if you mark the answer like accepted, (click the check mark)